# Haskell Criterion Usage Error

Tags: haskell, package, benchmarking, ghc, haskell-criterion

The following code named `fib.hs`

```
import Criterion.Main (defaultMain)
fibZ = 1:1:zipWith (+) fibZ (tail fibZ)
main = defaultMain [
         bench "fibZ 10" $ \n -> fibZ (10+n-n)
       ]
```

errors with

```
fib.hs:45:10: Not in scope: `bench'
```

What is wrong? I have borrowed this example from [here](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2009/09/29/criterion-a-new-benchmarking-library-for-haskell/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library has changed since that blog post was written. Now you should write:

```
 import Criterion.Main

 fib :: Int -> Int
 fib 0 = 0
 fib 1 = 1
 fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

 main = defaultMain [
        bgroup "fib" [ bench "fib 10" $ B fib 10
                     , bench "fib 35" $ B fib 35
                     , bench "fib 37" $ B fib 37
                     ]
                    ]
```

This was taken directly from the "Running benchmarks" section of [the Hackage documentation for Criterion.Main](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/criterion/0.4.1.0/doc/html/Criterion-Main.html).

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
import Criterion.Main
```

instead of

```
import Criterion.Main (defaultMain)
```

The function [`bench`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/criterion/0.4.1.0/doc/html/Criterion-Main.html#v:bench) from `Criterion.Main` is not in scope because you're importing only `defaultMain`. Using `bgroup` is not necessary.

Here's a full working example:

```
import Criterion.Main

fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main = defaultMain [
         bench "fib 10" $ nf fib 10
       , bench "fib 30" $ nf fib 30
       , bench "fib 35" $ nf fib 35
       ]
```

If you're wondering what these `nf` thingies are for, look at [this section](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/criterion/0.5.1.0/doc/html/Criterion-Main.html#g:3) of the documentation.

Comment: Your code errors for me as `fib.hs:53:37: Not in scope: data constructor `B'
Failed, modules loaded: none.` Sorry but I'm really new to Haskell.

Comment: You are probably talking about Jeremy's code - he copy-pasted his example from the doc page for an older version of criterion. Mine compiles without errors.

Comment: Sigh, now the code loads but instead I get an error when I call main: `Loading package double-conversion-0.2.0.1 ... can't load .so/.DLL for: stdc++ (libstdc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)`. I'm using GHC 7.0.4 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I think it's a known bug - fortunately, this happens only when you try to run your program in GHCi. Try compiling (with `ghc --make -O2`).

Comment: Now it runs but it only supports output type CSV. All other including PNG, PDF, SVG and win fails with an error like `ERROR: output type PDF 432 324 not supported on this platform`. Any clues?

Comment: These [are not enabled by default](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/criterion/0.5.1.0/criterion.cabal). Try `cabal install --reinstall criterion -fChart -fgtk` This will recompile criterion with support for drawing charts and displaying graphs in a gtk window.

Comment: Ok, when I reinstall criterion I get `setup: The program gtk2hsC2hs version >=0.13.5 is required but the version
found at /usr/bin/gtk2hsC2hs is version 0.13.4`. Do I have to wait for GHC 7.2.1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4403/discussion-between-nordlow-and-mikhail-glushenkov)

Comment: My inital guess was right - you have an old version of gtk2hs-buildtools, and since [build tools are not considered dependencies by `cabal-install`](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/227), you should update them manually. Do `cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools` and then `cabal install --reinstall criterion -fChart -fgtk`.